# why is laravel running a select query while am inserting

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5

**I'm trying to insert data into my database but I kept on getting this error since I Dropped a table called categories with which has an eloquent relationship with another table**

The funny thing is Laravel is running a select query from a dropped table while my code is an insert query..

```
{
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'train.categories' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `categories` where `name` = Oil Drilling)",
"exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
"file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\enter code heretrain\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php",
"line": 664,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\train\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php",
        "line": 624,
        "function": "runQueryCallback",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\train\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php",
        "line": 333,
        "function": "run",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
        "type": "->"
    },

]
```

}

This my insert code

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
     $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:250|unique:categories',
        'image' => 'required|image',
        'price' => 'required',
        'duration' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'url' => 'string'
    ]);
    if ( $request->hasFile('image') ) {

        $ext = $request->image->extension();
        $iconName =  str_slug('storage/'.$request->name).'.'.$ext;
        $request->image->storeAs('public',$iconName);

        DB::table('courses')->insert(
            [
                'name' => $request->name,
                'image' => $iconName,
                'url' => $request->url,
                'price' => $request->price,
                'duration' => $request->duration,
                'description' => $request->description
            ]
        );
        return response()->json([
            'success'=>true,
            'image' => $iconName
        ]); 
    }
    return response()->json(['error' => false]); 
}
```

Comment: Your select probably comes from validation `'name' => 'required|string|max:250|unique:categories'`.

Comment: Thanks alot I have wasted more they 24 hours on this

Answer (score 0):

Check the unique:categories on the below line

name' => 'required|string|max:250|unique:categories

U may know what it is... But let me explain
The unique will check for the given name already exist in categories table. Bit u dont have that table. So it will give u that error